# Approach to analysing big data

Tags: r, sas, pandas

I’m trying to analyse quite a largish dataset. The sasdb7 is around 11GB and the csv is around 9GB. This is after merging the datasets, cleaning and removing unnecessary columns.

I am comfortable using SAS, R and Python (Pandas). I would prefer to use Python for this.

The columns of the dataset look something like this:

Sales-of-product Date Store Product othervars

e.g Date is not a unique variable as it is the sales of the product per store per day.

What would your approach be here?

How should I approach loading in such a large file? I don’t think my computer memory will handle it. Pandas seems to have chunks but will that work with inbuilt functions like regression?

I am thinking any exploratory analysis would involve taking a sample of the data somehow? And then plotting..How should I do this? Sort by and take every nth ?

I’m assuming I’ll need some date ordering too to control for autocorrelation?

Given the number of potential variables, would a neural net be useful here? Rather than a regression?

Thanks for any help/advice ☺️

Comment: Not a full answer, but regarding sampling, your best bet is probably to just do it randomly, unless there are rare sample groups that you want to be sure you represent. Sorting and taking every n could get you a good cross-section across the variable you sort over, but you could inadvertently introduce bias over the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

Sample a subset of the rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
# total_rows, sample_rows
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", skiprows=random.sample(range(total_rows), k=total_rows-sample_rows)
```

Also, you may be unable to load everything into memory, but you maybe be able to load all rows if you just select a couple of columns:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", usecols=["colname1", "colname2"])
```

It really depends on what you want to do.